# How can i drop my mesh on floor with rigid body

Tags: collision, rigidbody

I have a floor and mesh (pen). Im dropping the pen on the floor. Floor is set to passive and pen to active. Added collision-on to floor. When the pen is not dropping on the floor. Its flickering in air. I want to add some few 8-10 pens on the floor so that it get collision with floor and with each. other.Any suggestion how it works.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try with primitive collision shapes?

Comment: Try changing the 'floor' plane to a box in the collision setting rather than a mesh.

Comment: No its not working

Comment: The floating is caused by collision margins set to 4 cm. The pen's shape is problematic, It's too low poly for mesh to work and too misshapen for convex hull. You could try scaling everything up by a factor of 100, too. Physics engine doesn't like small things.

Comment: @Ron Jensen, is there any need for collision ? Just a rigid body physics will do the job properly right ?

Comment: Collision is for soft-body (cloth, fluid) simulations.

Comment: Right , so there is no need for collision here . Deleting it solved the problem for me. Thanks for answering my question ; )

Comment: @RonJensen But i added collision reason is , when i copied 8-10 pen and then try to do collision on floor and each other pen. that time also did not work. the pens merge each other. any solution

Comment: It works for me as Ron Jensen suggested. He pointed all aspects correctly. In this scale I was able to stop moving only with Box. Also it s always good to have Origin in center of Object. @RonJensen please could you write it as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I tried a few options and got a fairly stable simulation. Here is the result:
[image: multiple pens falling and colliding with the ground]

**Steps:**

- Scale the ground and pen up by 100 (physics simulations work better with larger objects. Also, the floating came from the constant collision margin of 4 cm which means that objects will already collide when they are 2*4 centimeters apart. While this value can be changed, it is better to scale the objects up)
- Apply the scale on the pen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > Scale
- Set the origin of the pen to *Center of Mass (Volume)* (a wrong origin can mess up simulations)
- Use convex hull as collision shape (should be precise enough in this case. Mesh shape causes glitches)
- Use box as collision shape for the ground (except if you want to use a different shape)
- Finally, you might want to increase the Rigidbody simulation steps (Go to `Scene Properties > Rigid Body World` and increase *Steps per Second* and *Solver Iterations*, e.g. to *600* and *100*)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If i want the same scale back. How it will work.

Comment: Bake sim and parent all pens to Empty. Scale down Empty